# write an array to a multidimensional array read from csv with php

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

i have the folowing array read from a csv file:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => book1
        [1] => description1
        [2] => category1
        [3] => code1
        [4] => editor1
        [5] => 0
        [6] => eur
        [7] => out of stoc
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => book2
        [1] => description2
        [2] => category2
        [3] => code2
        [4] => editor2
        [5] => 0
        [6] => curr2
        [7] => out of stoc
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => book3
        [1] => description3
        [2] => category3
        [3] => code3
        [4] => editor3
        [5] => 0
        [6] => curr3
        [7] => out of stoc
    )

)
```

Code :

```
function read_CSV_raza($rzs_csv) {
$file_handle = fopen($rzs_csv, 'r');
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
$line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024, ';');
}
fclose($file_handle);
return $line_of_text;
}

$rzs_csv = 'rzs.csv';
$csv = read_CSV_raza($rzs_csv);
```

I want to add another array (headers) in order to write this intro another csv file.
EX :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
    [0] => h1
    [1] => h2
    [2] => h3
    [3] => h4
    [4] => h5
    [5] => h6
    [6] => h7
    [7] => h8
)
[1] => Array
(
    [0] => book1
    [1] => description1
    [2] => category1
    [3] => code1
    [4] => editor1
    [5] => 0
    [6] => eur
    [7] => out of stoc
)

[2] => Array
(
    [0] => book2
    [1] => description2
    [2] => category2
    [3] => code2
    [4] => editor2
    [5] => 0
    [6] => curr2
    [7] => out of stoc
)

[3] => Array
(
    [0] => book3
    [1] => description3
    [2] => category3
    [3] => code3
    [4] => editor3
    [5] => 0
    [6] => curr3
    [7] => out of stoc
)

)
```

I tried with array_merge(); array_unshift(); but to no avail, i do not get the results i need.

The cod for writing the array in the new CSV is :

```
$fp = fopen('rezultate.csv', 'w') or die("Can't open rezultate.csv");
foreach ($csv as $items) {
fputcsv($fp, $items, ';', '"');
}
fclose($fp) or die("Can't close rezultate.csv");
```

As i am not a programmer any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just do an `fputcsv($fp, $headers, ';', '"');` immediately before your `foreach ($csv as $items)` loop.... it's a lot more efficient than array_unshift()

Comment: just did but now it only writes the headers not the array

Comment: `$fp = fopen('rezultate.csv', 'w') or die("Can't open rezultate.csv"); fputcsv($fp, $headers, ';', '"');
foreach ($csv as $items) {
fputcsv($fp, $items, ';', '"');
}
fclose($fp) or die("Can't close rezultate.csv");`

Comment: thank you so much works like a dream!

Answer (score 0):

`array_unshift` worked for me:

```
$add = array (
    0 => "h1",
    1 => "h2",
    2 => "h3",
    3 => "h4",
    4 => "h5",
    5 => "h6",
    6 => "h7",
    7 => "h8"
);
array_unshift($myarray, $add);
```

And also

```
array_unshift($myarray, array(0 => "h1", 1 => "h2", 2 => "h3", 3 => "h4", 4 => "h5", 5 => "h6", 6 => "h7", 7 => "h8"));
```